# How to extract value from log with grok and logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I must extract value from a log composed by row like this:

```
<38>1 [2017-03-15T08:45:23.168Z] apache.01.mysite.com event=login;src_ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;site=FE-B1-Site;cstnr=1454528;user=498119;result=SUCCESS
```

For example with %{IP:source}
I obtain only the first IP but, sometimes, I have 3 IP address.
How I can extract all IP,'cstnr', 'result' and 'user' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a nested, delimited key-value format. First delimiter is `;`, with each of those a `key=value`. Additionally, the values are delimited on `,`'. You have enough grok to get the first IP address, but I suggest doing something a bit different:

1. Use `grok` to grab the entire string after your site-name.
2. Use the `kv` filter with `field_split => ';'`, which will create fields named the same as your keys.
3. Use the `csv` filter on the `src_ip` address captured in the `kv` filter stage.

   - Use `columns => [ cstnr', 'result', 'user' ]` to get those fields named right.